# looking for asp.net navigation menu editor with source code

Tags: asp.net, menu, navigation, sitemap

web-based so it can be used by users and hopefully using the class SQLSiteMapProvider which allows for saving sitemap in a SQL Database instead of XML.

Answer (score 1):

You may create the menu using following or similar code. More details are here in following [Tutorial at Asp.Net](http://www.asp.net/learn/data-access/tutorial-03-cs.aspx)
You may modify this code block and use **SQLSiteMapProvider** instead of **SiteMapDataSource**

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lnkHome"
         NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx">Home</asp:HyperLink></li>

        <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="menu"
          DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <li>
                    <asp:HyperLink runat="server"
                    NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>'>
                    <%# Eval("Title") %></asp:HyperLink>
                </li>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ul>

    <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1"
      runat="server" ShowStartingNode="false" />
</div>
```